# Unity level light and laser seems diffrent after build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have laser light in my gun.In editor screen everything ok but when i build my game i see diffrent things.One other thing my game lighting is diffrent then editor.Why this is happening ?

Left pic. build Right is in editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your shaders is not working, that solid magenta replaces missing or broken shaders. You haven't provided enough info to diagnose the problem, however. On which build target(s) does this happen, and is it consistent across all of them? What is the shader you are using on that object?